# Rotate Image .pbm Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, rotation, ppm

i need help about a rotation or spin matrix in haskell

i have a list of list, of a data type RGB:

```
data RGBdata= RGB Int Int Int

m = [[(RGB 0 255 255),(RGB 255 0 0)],[(RGB 255 255 255),(RGB 255 0 0)]]
```

to be seen better i have a matrix 2x2:

```
m = [[(RGB 1 2 3),(RGB 4 5 6)],
     [(RGB 7 8 9),(RGB 1 5 9)]]
```

and i need 90° rotation, i mean something like:

```
m = [[(RGB 7 8 9),(RGB 1 2 3)]
     [(RGB 1 5 9),(RGB 4 5 6)]]
```

Extends my explication, i have 2 data type:

```
data RGBdata= RGB Int Int Int
data PBMfile= PBM Int Int [[RGBdata]]
```

and my function receive:

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((transpose . reverse) l))
```

where 'x' and 'y' is the number of colums and rows respectively (maybe can help to do the function).

I try rotate 90° to the left with your anwer and the image result is wrong.

i try

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((reverse . transpose) l))
```

and

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((transpose . reverse) l))
```

and

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y (((map reverse) . transpose) l))
```

to rotate the image but does not work.

the result is something like

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/catmc.jpg/

Comment: What you are describing is not a rotation matrix.  A rotation matrix is a matrix `A` such that `A*x` performs rotation on `x`.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: `transpose . reverse`

If you're planning to use lists to store large images, bear in mind that it will probably be inefficient, since there's five boxed values (a lot of bytes) for every pixel.  It'd be more efficient to use an unboxed Vector or Array instead.  Just giving you a heads up.

That said, let's look at list operations in terms of what they do to the image.

```
> let demo f = mapM_ print $ f m
> demo id
[RGB 1 2 3,RGB 4 5 6]
[RGB 7 8 9,RGB 1 5 9]
> demo reverse
[RGB 7 8 9,RGB 1 5 9]
[RGB 1 2 3,RGB 4 5 6]
> demo (map reverse)
[RGB 4 5 6,RGB 1 2 3]
[RGB 1 5 9,RGB 7 8 9]
> demo (transpose)
[RGB 1 2 3,RGB 7 8 9]
[RGB 4 5 6,RGB 1 5 9]
```

- `reverse` flips the image vertically (by reversing the rows)
- `map reverse` flips the image horizontally (by reversing the pixels in each row)
- `transpose` flips the image along the `\` diagonal line.

Now, find a piece of paper, and figure out how to perform the desired rotation in terms of these operations (modeling `transpose` is tricky if your paper is rectangular).  Remember that any time you see the back of the paper, the image will appear mirrored.  Since each of these operations turns the paper around, you need an even number of them to perform a rotation.

The only rotation you can do with `reverse` and `map reverse` is turn the paper upside down.  This means you'll need `transpose` to rotate the image 90°.

`transpose` (diagonal flip) followed by `reverse` (vertical flip) rotates the image 90° to the *left*:

```
> demo (reverse . transpose)
[RGB 4 5 6,RGB 1 5 9]
[RGB 1 2 3,RGB 7 8 9]
```

On the other hand, `reverse` (vertical flip) followed by `transpose` (diagonal flip) rotates the image 90° to the *right* (which you want):

```
> demo (transpose . reverse)
[RGB 7 8 9,RGB 1 2 3]
[RGB 1 5 9,RGB 4 5 6]
```

Comment: hello friend, i try spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((transpose . reverse) l)) and does not work.. please help me

Comment: @user495943: Assuming `x` and `y` are the width and height of the image, you need to make sure that you swap those as well.

Comment: maybe using 'x' and 'y' can rotate, but the combination "reverse,transpose" does not work yet

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, it looks like you want `map reverse . transpose`, where `transpose` is in `Data.List`:

```
> let x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
> map reverse . transpose $ x
[[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]]
```

Note that this is probably slower than necessary if your input list is large enough, but that'll likely only come into play if your list is 1000 by 1000 or if you're doing this in a tight inner loop.