# Rotation Matrix PBMfile Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, rotation, ppm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotate Image .pbm Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407003/rotate-image-pbm-haskell)

i need help about a rotation matrix in haskell

i have 2 data type:

```
data RGBdata= RGB Int Int Int
data PBMfile= PBM Int Int [[RGBdata]]
```

and my function receive:

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((transpose . reverse) l))
```

where 'x' and 'y' is the number of colums and rows respectively (maybe can help to do the function).

for example:

```
(PBM 2 2 [[(RGB 0 255 255),(RGB 255 0 0)],[(RGB 255 255 255),(RGB 255 0 0)]])
```

I try rotate 90° to the left using combinations with reverse and transpose, but the image result is wrong.

i try

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((reverse . transpose) l))
```

and

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y ((transpose . reverse) l))
```

and

```
spin :: PBMfile -> PBMfile
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM x y (((map reverse) . transpose) l))
```

to rotate the matrix but does not work.

the result is something like

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/52/catmc.jpg/

Comment: "the image result is wrong"... but wrong in what way? Try phrasing your question in the form "I did X, expecting Y, but Z happened instead.".

Comment: i add explication, to help us to understand

Comment: Not only for us to understand, but also for you to test your functions. What is the result of applying kunwoo32's solution to your own example?

Answer (score 2):

The transpose operation should happen before the reverse operation. Try

```
spin (PBM x y l) = (PBM y x ((reverse . transpose) l))
```

Also the dimensions of the rotated images are switched.

Comment: I try, and does not work .. I get the image has a diagonal line that divide it. thanks

Comment: In your example in your question, your matrix seems to be rotating clockwise. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, to rotate the image

Answer (score 1):

You need to also consider `(map reverse)`, not just `transpose` and `reverse`.  I think `((map reverse) . transpose)` does what you want.

Comment: does not work men, i try and and is really close but is reversed